# How order words from a text file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I've written a Python script which I use to print out all words from a text file:

```
file = open(raw_input("Enter a file name: "))

for line in file:
    for words in line.split():
        print words
```

But how to print them out in order?

Comment: Print them out in what order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to sort the words in each line you can use `sorted`:

```
with open(raw_input("Enter a file name: ")) as f :

   for line in f:
      for words in sorted(line.split()):
        print words
```

But if you want to print all the words in a sorted order you need to apply the sort on all words :

```
with open(raw_input("Enter a file name: ")) as f :
     for t in sorted(i for line in f for i in line.split()):
           print t
```